# How to mark a lacquered surface

Tags: wood, polyurethane

A cabinet door is stained dark and has a clear coat on it. How can I mark it? I want to mark locations for pre-drilling and I find magic markers or various usual writing tools not that good at marking the surface.

Comment: Why not simply scribe your locations with a sharp tool?

Comment: @Huesmann  That is an option if you are sure. If you find yourself making mistakes and changing your mind then all the scratch marks become confusing.  With me trying to drill hinges for fresh cabinet doors as a newbie the masking tape was good. Just don't forget to remove the tape!

Answer (score 6):

Get some painter's tape or masking tape and apply it to the cabinet. Then make your marks on the tape for your predrilling.

Comment: A white grease pencil might also work, but will tend to get caught in any scratches and isn't a very precise indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Milwaukee INKZALL. Or any oil-based marker. Buy a few. Once you try them, you'll find uses everywhere.